# How do you translate "Es para que hubiera más cafeterías" into English?

Tags: sentence-construction, translation, learning

Today I was at school talking with a friend about there are a lot of students but very few cafeterias,so he said

> Es para que hubiera más cafeterías.

I was trying to figure out how to translate that sentence into English, so far I do not have very clear how it could be translated, I think it could be translated as:

> There should be more cafeterias.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I agree with your translation.

Comment: I agree too, but idiomatically, it corresponds exactly to “you’d think...” about something that perplexes you: “Con tantos estudiantes en esta escuela es para que hubiera más cafeterías.” - With so many students at this school, you’d think they’d have more cafeterias. Another example: Después de cinco años en España es para que John hablara mejor español. = After five years in Spain, you’d think John would speak better Spanish. Hope this helps)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most faithful translation:

> It (the situation) is such that there should have been more cafeterias.

One of the challenges of this question is that the statement in Spanish is not exactly precise and is somewhat colloquial and conversational.

Your friend could have simply said, "Hubiera más cafeterías," and the same meaning would have been conveyed.

The connecting phrase "es para que" is common in conversational constructs, and is simply an informal lead-in or transition.

Comment: Is Spanish your native language? Or English?

Comment: Yes! ;) Grew up with both. My parents taught me both. Migrated to US in 2001, now I use both about 50-50.

Answer (score 1):

You’d think there'd be more cafeterias!

Comment: And just to clarify - "There'd" is a more conversational or casual way to say "there would".

Comment: As is, that sentence is not quite right. "*You'd* think there'd be more cafeterias!", short for "You would think there would be more cafeterias!" is better English, and what people really say. In other words:, "If you knew about the situation, you *would* think ....[whatever]." "You think ... [whatever]." just tries to tell the listener what he thinks.